# How to use linq to entity to allow the user choose which columns must be chosen in query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

Anyone knows how to allow users to choose which columns of a table(all columns listed in `radCheckedDropDownList`) must be chosen in query and displayed in `DataGridView`?
I want something like this but it is do not work:

```
var bas= new SaleToFreightageEntities();
                bas.DetailsView.Select(a =>
                {
                    dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
                    if (radCheckedDropDownList1.CheckedItems.Select(t=>t.Text=="Column1").Any()) d.A = a.Radifkolsal;
                    if (radCheckedDropDownList1.CheckedItems.Select(t=>t.Text=="Column2").Any()) d.B = a.Rahgiry;
                    return d;
                });
```

Comment: Add what you have done so far

Comment: still nothing, I'm just finding a way to do that.

Comment: Use a Select with a dynamic object and add only the properties you need.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: Not very nice but you can get the idea: `context.Whatever.Select(e => { dynamic d = new ExpandoObject(); if(useFieldA) d.A = e.A; if(useFieldB) d.B = e.B; return d; })`

Comment: it's a little bit hard for me to understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: Please post the code snippet that you have written so far so that we can help.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have any code yet, so I'm trying to find a way to do that or any simple example to find it out.

Comment: a sample code added

Comment: Are there so many possible properties that it becomes a performance concern to simply return them all? The hiding or showing of certain properties is typically a concern of the view - in your case, the DataGridView.

Comment: you are right, but there is so many columns (about 90) that i don't want to query all of them because of performance, so i need that the user chose what he need to see in Grid.